# How to center labels in FlexLayout Nativescript vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I want the labels shown inside the flexlayout appears centered, but it doesn,t.

```html
 <FlexboxLayout justifyContent="center">                    
  <Label textWrap="false" v-for="(item,index) in palabra_escrita"  v-bind:text="item"  v-bind:key="index" />                                                        
 </FlexboxLayout>
```

This adds certains labels depending the length of the array palabra_escrita.

[image]

Comment: What about the rest of the code? The snippet you posted looks correct. Maybe the labels have some wrong styling, share more please

Comment: Please, i have just added the code. Thanks

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue on both iOS & Android with given code snippet. Please share a Playground sample if issue still persists.

Comment: I have fixed wit this:  <FlexboxLayout  justifyContent="center"   height="100"  >
        
        <Label v-for="(item,index) in palabra_escrita" width="34"  v-bind:text="item"  v-bind:key="index" alignSelf="center"  /> 
        
    </FlexboxLayout>